# Two active partitions on Windows 10 - wont boot if one is removed

Tags: windows, windows-10, boot, partitioning

I am running a 64-bit version of Windows 10. Yesterday my system experienced boot error *0xc00000f*.

I tried to solve the error by creating a Windows ISO media USB stick and repair the boot file as indicated [here](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/windows-10-boot-error-0xc000000f/1888b13b-b291-4e67-99d6-53bd34903903).

Problems arised when running `bootrec /fixboot` which gave the error message `Access denied` and `bootrec /rebuildbcd` which would find a Windows installation in the first place, but after accepting it could not find the drive (compare also Link above).

I then tried to solve the `Access denied` problem by following the steps indicated [on this site](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-performance/windows-10-bootrec-fixboot-access-is-denied/747c4180-7ff3-4bc2-b6cc-81e572d546df).

This has partially fixed my problem in a way that my system does now boot again, but only when the USB drive is inserted. I have checked drive partitions to find the following:

> Picture description:  german - english;
>
> Disk 0: System-reservier -
>   system reserved, Fehlerfrei- healthy, Primäre Partition - Primary
>   Partition; (C:) Healthy (Boot, Page File, Active, Crash Dump, Primary
>   Partition); 895MB Healthy (Recovery Parition)
>
> Disk 1: Healthy (Active,
>   Primary Partition)

[image: Image showing C: partition is marked active and labelled as boot partition ["Startpartition"]. USB drive [Disk 1] is also marked active.]

Booting into windows without the USB drive does not work. 
**How can I achieve the usual boot behavior again?**

edit2:

```
C:\windows\system32>bcdedit.exe /enum

Windows-Start-Manager  
---------------------   
Bezeichner              {bootmgr}  
device                  partition=\Device\HarddiskVolume4  
path                    \EFI\Microsoft\Boot\bootmgfw.efi  
description             Windows Boot Manager  
locale                  en-us  
inherit                 {globalsettings}  
default                 {current}  
resumeobject            {82e838ae-e42c-11e9-b1cf-e2c34e172c0b}  
displayorder            {current}  
toolsdisplayorder       {memdiag}  
timeout                 30  

Windows-Startladeprogramm  
-------------------------
Bezeichner              {current}  
device                  partition=C:  
path                    \windows\system32\winload.efi  
description             Windows 10  
locale                  en-us  
inherit                 {bootloadersettings}  
isolatedcontext         Yes  
allowedinmemorysettings 0x15000075  
osdevice                partition=C:  
systemroot              \windows  
resumeobject            {82e838ae-e42c-11e9-b1cf-e2c34e172c0b}  
nx                      OptIn  
bootmenupolicy          Standard
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.  Questions are expected to be written in English, this includes providing a English translation, to any text that might exist in a screenshot that isn't English.  Knowing the exact commands you used might also be helpful.  Please include this information in the question body itself.

Comment: Err.. @Ramhound did you read the question? All of these are included, including a screengrab. Did you use the wrong template? :)

Comment: Provide your current BCD entries. *Your screenshot contains words, I am not familar with, my inability to read that language.*  So I used the correct "template" for my comment.

Comment: @Ramhound, does this held you?
Else, you should please explicitly tell me what you need from the bdcedit.exe

Comment: What disk contains the EFI partition?  The HDD that contains Windows or the external media(\Device\HarddiskVolume4)?  You can use DiskPart to determine which disk `HarddiskVolume4` is on.

Comment: Your screenshot shows two individual disks, your system partition is on the first disk, the EFI partition is on the second disk.  The 14.4 GB partition appears to be your EFI partition, I say this due to the fact, the EFI partition must be FAT32.  *The fact he partition is active has very little to do with your problems.*

Comment: Do you have a recommendation how to solve this? (I suspect moving EFI backt to the systems harddrive?)